# two dividers in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[screenshot of drawer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0vnljid1j7cxjg/Screenshot_2014-07-27-17-10-12.png) 
i have an android navigation drawer in my app.everything works fine but when my drawer is visible it has two divider lines between the items.
one in red(which i think i have made) and the other in white(which i dont know where it came from)

here are my two drawer files

custom_drawer_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/itemlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"

    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="60dp"

       >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:paddingRight="6dp"
             android:paddingTop="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                  android:textSelectHandleLeft="@+id/drawer_icon"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff"

                  android:paddingTop="10dp"
                         />
      </LinearLayout>

     <View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
  android:background="#DADADC"

   ></View>

</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<FrameLayout 
     android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</FrameLayout>

 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/leftdrawer"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#B80000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#076672"

    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

if you'll still cant get it please ask me for the image.il show
thnx in advance

Comment: can you attach the image?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0vnljid1j7cxjg/Screenshot_2014-07-27-17-10-12.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have a `View` like this:

```
<View
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:background="#DADADC">
</View>
```

in bottom of your `custom_drawer_item.xml` layout.

Comment: thanx it worked!! but what was it doing can you telme?

Comment: @Farhanpatel it's simple. Yoh have a divider in listview by this code in red color: `android:divider="#B80000"` in your `activity_main.xml` and have a `View` with height of 1dp which have a nearly white value. Then listview load each row from `custom_drawer_item.xml`. So yo seen two divider.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of these two dividers line is the divider of ListView, the other is the view you added in your custom_drawer_item.xml, which has 1dp height.
You can remove the one that you don't want.